# Ajax jquery sending Null value to Mvc4 controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem related the ajax call request searched for it on stack overflow tried all the related help that i got but can't solve the problem. the problem is that i request to a controller from my view using this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#contactDiv ').click(function() {

           var  number = $(this).find('.ContactNumber').text();

            var dataJson = {"contactNumber": number};

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../contactWeb/messages",
               data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
               //data: dataJson,
                 //contentType: "application/json",
                  contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    //msg for success and error.....
                    alert(msg);
                    return true;
                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

and the controller that receives the call is

```
      [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult messages(string dataJson) 
        {

            Int64 userID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["userId"]);
            try
            {
                List<MessagesModel> messagesModel = new List<MessagesModel>();
                IMessages MessageObject = new MessagesBLO();

                messagesModel = MessageObject.GetAllMessagesWeb(userID , dataJson);

                //ViewData["Data"] = messagesModel;



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            //return View();

            string msg = "Error while Uploading....";
            return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

but it passes NULL value to the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi could you change the name of your parameters `string dataJson` in your action to `contactNumber` in respect to the object you pass via your Ajax call

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult messages(string contactNumber) //here
    {

        Int64 userID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["userId"]);
        try
        {
            List<MessagesModel> messagesModel = new List<MessagesModel>();
            IMessages MessageObject = new MessagesBLO();

            messagesModel = MessageObject.GetAllMessagesWeb(userID , contactNumber); //and here

            //ViewData["Data"] = messagesModel;



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        //return View();

        string msg = "Error while Uploading....";
        return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: ya but thanks i got it now... "aplication/json" should be there instead of  just "json"

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of issues need to be fixed

whats the need of

```
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
```

when your `action` type is `post`.

If you are using `asp.net mvc4` use `Url.Action` to specify url i.e

```
url:"@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")"
```

Now Talking about your issue.

Your parameter names must match, change `dataJson` to `contactNumber`.Though its ok to use there isnt any need to use `JSON.stringify` as you are passing single string parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult messages(string contactNumber) 
        {

            Int64 userID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["userId"]);
```

Comment: ya but thanks i got it now... "aplication/json" should be there instead of just "json"

Answer (score -4):

If you want to get JSON in messages() try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#contactDiv ').click(function() {

           var  number = $(this).find('.ContactNumber').text();

            var data = {"contactNumber": number};
            var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../contactWeb/messages",
               dataType: 'text',
               data: "dataJson=" + dataJson,
               //data: dataJson,
                 //contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    //msg for success and error.....
                    alert(msg);
                    return true;
                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```